# Mongoose Count documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got the below query to return a random user from my users schema:

```
UserSchema.statics.random = function(id,callback) {
  this.count(function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
    this.findOne()
    .where('_id').ne(id)
    .where('last_active').gte(new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-3)))
    .skip(rand)
    .exec(callback);
  }.bind(this));
};
```

However sometime it returns `NULL` - I'd think this is because it's counting the documents first then applying filters which reduces the count of documents so the `rand` value could be higher than the number of documents available.

I can't seem to think what a better way would be to do this?

Would I run the above query, count the documents then run another query with the `.skip()` parameter?

Comment: Unless you know how many documents are matched with the `last_active` check, you often will `skip` beyond the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `findOne()`, you want just `find()` but `limit(1).skip(rand)`. As @WiredPrairie commented, you also need to make sure your `.count` query is the same as your `.find` query so  you minimize the chances of skipping past the end. It will still be possible if records are deleted between the `count` and the `find` though. Here's an untested snippet:

```
UserSchema.statics.random = function(id, callback) {
  var conditions = {
    _id: {$ne: id},
    //not sure WTF you are trying to do here, but consider moment.js
    // Users must be active within the last 3 days
    last_active: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-3))
  };

  this.count(conditions, function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
    this.find(conditions).limit(1).skip(rand).exec(callback);
  }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Thanks so something like this: [GIST](https://gist.github.com/Tam2/9c3c300693caae9ec423)